# Action bar / button background fill

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

On some devices (such as older Samsung devices, the "Scroll Extreme" tablet this screenshot was taken on), the action bar and some buttons do not appear with the correct background or only partially filled. In the screenshot below, you can faintly see a button with white text which is missing a background.

[image]

The app only targets API level 14+ and is therefore not using the support lib or ActionBarSherlock. The style for the action bar is as follows:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarSubTitleText</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarSubTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

PS. the colours seen in the screenshot have not been correctly captured by the screenshot app, but the idea is there!

Comment: So you say that when this button is in the `ActionBar` it looks like what you have shown in the screenshot? I guess that is correct as you are using white text on a `Light` `ActionBar`. Maybe the problem is that the button is selected? You are not using a selector drawable so you are not in control what happens to the background when it is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can be solved by changing the below to use a drawable as opposed to a color.

```
 <item name="android:background">@color/accent</item>
```

Example drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/accent" />
</shape>
```